# Windows: Mapping network traffic of an IP and port to another IP and port on the local machine

Tags: port-forwarding

On windows, I need to map all the traffic of an IP address (e.g. 10.255.255.255) to another (e.g. 127.0.0.1).

I came across netsh interface portproxy and I have tried it.

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=10.255.255.255 listenport=7073 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=7071`

The goal is if a user sends any packet to `10.255.255.255:7073` it's like she sends the packets to `127.0.0.1:7071`

```
netsh interface portproxy show all

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
10.255.255.255  7073        127.0.0.1         7071
```

I've also added the firewall rule for the 7073 port.

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="7073 port" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=7073 action=allow`

This is on Windows 11.

The results of netstat -na|find "7073" is empty and the  same result for 7071 is as follows

```
netstat -na|find "7071"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7071           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

In my application, I first tried from postman to send the request to 10.255.255.255:7073 and I've got a timeout. The same request can be sent successfully to 127.0.0.1:7071.

If I do telnet to the 7073, it cannot connect to it.

```
telnet 10.255.255.255 7073
Connecting To 10.255.255.255...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7073: Connect failed
```

I have checked `IP Helper` service is also running.

My intention is if users already could send requests to `127.0.0.1:7071`, after port forwarding, they can send requests to `10.255.255.255:7073` and see the same behavior. My application actually sends HTTP requests.

Note that NO service is actually listening on `7073` which is the incoming traffic. But that's the point, I want anyone who sends anything to this port (even though no one is listening on it), the traffic goes to `7071` (which someone is listening on it).

Regarding mapping an IP:port to another to forward all the network traffic back/forth from source IP to dest IP, is my approach correct?

If yes, what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if it's supposed to work if none of the interfaces has the listenaddress assigned on it. This sound no more than a redirect rule to me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `netsh` command is when specifying the
parameters of `listenaddress` and `connectaddress`, which are for
**one specific IP address, not for a range of addresses**.

The syntax `10.255.255.255` that you used therefore specifies
this exact IP address and not the whole range of `10.*`
addresses.

The documentation for
[Netsh interface portproxy commands - add v4tov4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4)
says this:

> **connectaddress**
>
> Specifies the *IPv4 address* to which to connect. Acceptable values are
> IP address, computer NetBIOS name, or computer DNS name. If an
> address isn't specified, the default is the local computer.
>
> **listenaddress**
>
> Specifies the *IPv4 address* for which to listen. Acceptable values are
> IP address, computer NetBIOS name, or computer DNS name. If an
> address isn't specified, the default is the local computer.

If you wish to recreate the portproxy, you will need
first to delete the one you created using
[delete v4tov4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#delete-v4tov4).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried without IPs and got error.`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7073 connectport=7071`
One or more essential parameters were not entered.
Verify the required parameters, and reenter them.
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't think 10.255.255.255 *has to be* a broadcast address when IPs are classless in reality. I think it can be used as a host address if you have 255.255.255.255 as the subnet mask. (And on the other hosts a host route is added for that.) I am not entirely sure if Windows allows that though.

Comment: Right, the point is this is a single IP anyway and I didn't quite get why @FrankThomas said this is a broadcast address. This is just a sample IP from Class A Private Range: 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255; and it doesn't matter if I select another IP such as 10.1.2.3 as the source.